# ReactJS. How to set state asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code. I'm trying to make a component that uploads multiple images asynchronously. This is just a simple version of my code to see the problem.

```
const Item = ({ item, onAsyncUpdate }) => {
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      onAsyncUpdate({id: item.id, value: "Updated list item"})
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID)
  }, [])

  return (
    <li>{item.id} - {item.value}</li>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [ items, setItems ] = React.useState([
    {id: 1, value: "List Item"},
    {id: 2, value: "List Item"},
    {id: 3, value: "List Item"},
    {id: 4, value: "List Item"},
    {id: 5, value: "List Item"},
  ])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Items list</h1>
      <ul>
        {items.map(item =>
          <Item
            item={item}
            onAsyncUpdate={updated => {
              setItems(items.map(el => updated.id == el.id ? updated : el))
            }}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
      
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I expected the result to be like this:

```
Items list
1 - Updated list item
2 - Updated list item
3 - Updated list item
4 - Updated list item
5 - Updated list item
```

But here is what I receive:

```
Items list
1 - List Item
2 - Updated list item
3 - List Item
4 - List Item
5 - List Item
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas on how to solve this problem?
Here is a CodePen example: https://codepen.io/grinev/pen/gOwEGXZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual `Item` is running its own `onAsyncUpdate` at the same time after App mounts, but that function:

```
setItems(items.map(el => updated.id == el.id ? updated : el))
```

, in its closure, contains the `items` that existed *in the initial render* of App. The stateful `items` doesn't get updated; the callback passed to an `Item` will always refer to the initial items, not to the items after an `onAsyncUpdate` has run.

Use the callback form instead to set the state:

```
setItems(items => items.map(el => updated.id == el.id ? updated : el))
```